# How do I append elements in another created element

Tags: javascript

I am createing a small game for a project. However I need to dynamicly add 9 td's (`<td>`) in each `tr`  using only `createElement` and `appendChild`

```
function trFunction() {
  var node = document.createElement("tr");
  var no = document.createElement("td");
  let tr = document.querySelector('tr')
  table1.appendChild(node);

}
let body = document.querySelector('body')
let table = document.createElement("table")
body.appendChild(table)
let table1 = document.querySelector('table')
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  trFunction()
}
```

Comment: you are already using `appendChild`, so why not use it inside `trFunction` to append `tr` into `td`  and `td` into `table`?

Comment: @CalvinNunes how do i do that?

Comment: exactly as you are doing on `body.appendChild(table)`... but instead of body you are going to use the variable holding `td`...  like this: `no.appendChild(tr)`.

Comment: Also, there's no need to re-select an element that you created. This: `let table1 = document.querySelector('table')` is not necessary, you already have a reference to the table, that is the variable `table`, no need to use the selector to get it again into table1

Comment: you're already using appendChild to add table to body and tr to table, just do the same thing to add td to tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating the table as you already did:
 `let table = document.createElement("table")`

Then append it to the body with: `document.body.appendChild(table)`, no need to find the table again as you did with `document.querySelector('table')`, because variable `table` already holds a reference to it.

Use the same logic inside the `trFunction`, create the `td`, then create the `tr`, append `tr` to `td` and `td` to `table`.

In my example below I used some CSS just to show it better (you can remove or style it as you wish). Also, you'll see that I added a parameter to the `trFunction`, called `number`, it is , again, just to examplify the code, if needed you can remove.

See the comments in the snippet code to understand it better

```js
let table = document.createElement("table") //CREATING TABLE (<table>)
document.body.appendChild(table);           //ADDING TO BODY

function trFunction(number) {
  var tdElem = document.createElement("td"); //CREATING <td>
  let trElem = document.createElement("tr"); //CREATING <tr>
  
  trElem.textContent = number; //JUST ADDING SOME TEXT TO tr (optional)
  
  tdElem.appendChild(trElem);  //APPENDING <tr> to <td>
  table.appendChild(tdElem);   //APPENDING <td> to <table>

}

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  trFunction(i)
}
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the element by using `getElementsByTagName` and use `innerHTML` to insert new HTML.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tr').innerHTML = '<td>your html here</td>';
```

Comment: i cant use innerhtml

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use innerHTML and why you cannot use appendChild  ?

Comment: It is a project and we were given instructions not to use it

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use `innerHTML` you can try `appendChild` or even `insertAdjecentHTML`

The `insertAdjacentHTML()` method. The first parameter is where you want the string appended and takes ("beforebegin", "afterbegin", "beforeend", "afterend"). As an example you could use "beforeend". The second parameter is just the html string.

Basic usage:

```
var yourVarHere = document.getElementById('your-elements-id');
yourVarHere.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<td>your html here</td>');
```

Or even using `getElementsByTagName`

```
var yourVarHere = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
yourVarHere.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<td>your html here</td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery "append" ?

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
$( ".container" ).append( "<h2>Greetings</h2>" );
```

It creates this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>  
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
</div>
```

https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: OP is not using jQuery, and he can only use `appendChild` as he stated in the question

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want to display our table of items -

```
const items =
  [ { name: "rice", cost: 1.6 }
  , { name: "beans", cost: 1.3 }
  , { name: "flour", cost: 2.0 }
  ]
```

We imagine some `table` function that could take two inputs, column headers and the row data, and it returns a `<table>...</table>` element -

```js
const t =
  table
    ( [ "name", "cost" ]               // columns
    , items.map(i => Object.values(i)) // rows
    )
```

Then we could insert our table element anywhere in the DOM -

```
document.body.appendChild(t)
```

To write `table`, we imagine some more functions:

1. An `html` function that takes a tag name and child nodes and returns `<tag>...childNodes</tag>`
2. A `row` function that accepts a string array and returns `<tr><td>str1</td><td>str2</td>...</tr>`

```js
const table = (headers = [], rows = []) =>
  html
    ( 'table'
    , html('thead', row(headers))
    , html('tbody', ...rows.map(row))
    )
```

We continue writing our program this way, imagining then implementing as we go. Writing `row` imagines `cell`. Writing `cell` imagines `text` -

```
const html = (tag, ...children) =>
{ const e = document.createElement(tag)
  children.forEach(c => e.appendChild(c))
  return e
}

const row = (cells = []) =>
  html('tr', ...cells.map(cell))

const cell = (s = "") =>
  html('td', text(s))

const text = (s = "") =>
  document.createTextNode(s)
```

At some point we are finally done. And voila! Once a thing of your imagination, `table` is now a working program. Click **Run** below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const table = (headers = [], rows = []) =>
  html
    ( 'table'
    , html('thead', row(headers))
    , html('tbody', ...rows.map(row))
    )

const row = (cells = []) =>
  html('tr', ...cells.map(cell))

const cell = (s = "") =>
  html('td', text(s))

const text = (s = "") =>
  document.createTextNode(s)

const html = (tag, ...children) =>
{ const e = document.createElement(tag)
  children.forEach(c => e.appendChild(c))
  return e
}

const items =
  [ { name: "rice", cost: 1.6 }
  , { name: "beans", cost: 1.3 }
  , { name: "flour", cost: 2.0 }
  ]

const t =
  table
    ( [ "name", "cost" ]
    , items.map(i => Object.values(i))
    )

document.body.appendChild(t)
```

```css
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```